# Is there an alternate syntax in Ruby for backticks?

Tags: ruby, operator-overloading, operators, backticks

In Ruby you can do `a + b`, which is equivalent to `a.+(b)`.

You can also override the `+()` method with `def +(other); end`.

Is there an alternate syntax for backticks? I know that this works:

```
class Foo
  def `(message)
    puts '<' + message + '>'
  end

  def bar
    `hello world`
  end
end

Foo.new.bar # prints "<hello world>"
```

But this won't work e.g.

```
Foo.new.`hello world`
```

Comment: Hint: if you want to call a method named `foo` with arguments, how do you do that?

Comment: How does `bar` work?

Comment: You must use `Foo.new.send(:\`, "hello_world")` but I assume that is not why you're trying to do this and you're trying to safely parse/eval some template. Sorry to say, but that is probably going to be a lot harder than you would think. The user could still use `::Kernel.send(:\`, 'foo')` or many many other tricks.

Comment: @KimmoLehto: There is no reason to use `send`. You can use normal method calling syntax. The problem is simply that the OP does not seem to understand what a normal method call in Ruby looks like.

Comment: @KimmoLehto: Using `send` is actually only in `irb`. As @JörgWMittag says it works fine in `rb`-file without `send`

Comment: I'm not trying to use this in production to e.g. do anything with templates. Just trying to understand Ruby's parser more thoroughly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between `.+` and backticks

From the context, `message` is `String`. So use quotation marks.

```
class Foo
  def `(message)
    puts '<' + message + '>'
  end
end

Foo.new.` 'hello world' #prints <hello world>
```

Due to codestyle is better to [use parentheses](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#method-invocation-parens)

```
Foo.new.`('hello world') #prints <hello world>
```

This code works perfectly in `rb`-file.

One might say that it doesn't work in `irb`. But `irb` is not a panacea (e.g. if you use `.` in the start of line, not in the end).
So if you want to use it in `irb`, call it as

```
Foo.new.send(:`, 'hello world')
```

Comment: It doesn't work, at least in 2.6.1 `irb`. And even if it did, it's not "alternate syntax for backtick".

Comment: @MarekLipka. It doesn't work in `irb`. But did you try to use this code in file says `backtricks.rb` and then run `ruby backtricks.rb`? It works. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that this won't work in `irb`. I see this as a shortcoming of irb's as opposed to this not being the properly-meant method-like (as opposed to operator-like) syntax.

Comment: @MarekLipka: IRb is well-known to be broken in various ways since it uses its own hand-written, not quite Ruby-compliant parser.